# How to find file when attaching Excel file to Outlook mail?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to send an Excel sheet to Outlook as an attachment.

I get an error on `.Attachments.Add NameFile`.

> cannot find this file. Verify the path and file name are correct

```vb
Sub sendMailTo()
    Dim ObjOutlook As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oBjMail
    Dim NameFile As String
    Dim Destination As String
    Dim Subject As String
       
    Set ObjOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Set oBjMail = ObjOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
       
    Destination = "mailadress@hotmail.com"
    Subject = "subject"
    NameFile = "SendThisSheet.xmls"
        
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=NameFile, _
      FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
    
    With oBjMail
        .To = "" & Destination
        .Subject = Subject
        .Body = "body"
        .Attachments.Add NameFile
        .Display True
        '.Send
    End With
    ObjOutlook.Quit
    Set oBjMail = Nothing
    Set ObjOutlook = Nothing
End Sub
```

The file is called SendThisSheet with the right extension and is saved this way as well if named differently. When debugging the NameFile variable is also filled in with this correct title.

Comment: Try putting the full path in.

Comment: But I want to it save on the fly, how can I know where this will be saved/stored on ones pc?

Comment: Get the path of the current file and use that or save it to the desktop or documents.

Comment: What I mean is, different people open/save this excel file on their pc and fill in a form. When they click the CTA the filled in excel file gets saved and send with outlook. Thats why I dont understand how I should now the path of the current file.

Comment: The original excel file knows its own path and you can pull that information. You could also use a generic location everyone has like desktop or documents. Maybe I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: I think I understand, you say to point the .saveAs to a directory. I will look up how to do that and report back. Thanks already my friend.

Comment: Yeah, and when you attach the file include that path as well, the save as and attach are probably looking at two different directories as their default.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to attach active Excel workbook to an email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255655/how-to-attach-active-excel-workbook-to-an-email)

Comment: You may find `.Attachments.Add (ActiveWorkbook.FullName)` is the correct version rather than `.Attachments.Add (ActiveDocument.FullName)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it looks like your error is a result of not having the workbook path included with the file name when trying to attach the file.

**Changing:**

```
.Attachments.Add NameFile
```

**To:**

```
.Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

Should do the trick.

Also just thought I'd point out; if you're trying to save the document as a macro-enabled workbook then the extension should be ".xlsm" instead of ".xmls"